# How to save a string in a sqlite database having adjcent ' ' in it through C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a string `Hi''Hello'''How r u'''` that I want to save in sqlite database through C#.
when I try doing that it throws the Exception

I have tried all the solutions currently present but still it is not working.

Comment: What is the exception? What is your code? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: SQL logic error or missing database

near "sdddfsdf": syntax error for this string ndjnjs'''''sdddfsdf'''''sdcdsdc''''

Comment: `create table t (s varchar2); insert into t values ("Hi''Hello'''How r u'''")';`

Answer (score 0):

`Hi''Hello'''How r u'''` you will see there are multiple Single quote (') so please replace' by `''`.
Like as `'Hi''Hello''How r u'''` it will work.

for ex. create data table

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
   SALARY         REAL
);
```

insert value >

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32,'California ', 20000.00 )
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California "and" Japan ', 20000.00 )
```

OR

```
 INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
    VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California ''and'' Japan ', 20000.00 )
```

it will insert but if you will try to insert

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California 'and' Japan ', 20000.00 )
```

it will break SQl query syntax near `'and'` and show error . So remove `'` quote or replace `'` by `' '`.

Comment: put your complete insert query also if still you are facing error.

Comment: But it will change my original string and I want to keep that as it is

Comment: you will have to replace `'` by `''` it is a solution. you can not insert single `'` inside the string.

Comment: I tried that but it is not working for adjacent single quotes

Comment: put your insert query here with string which you want to insert

Comment: `insert into xyz(id, Message) values(1,'Hi''Hello''How r u''')` it will work.

Comment: '''''sdddfsdf''''' add single `'` after and before this string or remove single `'` from both sides.

Comment: update chart set ChartName='" + chart.ChartName + "' where ChartId='" + chart.ChartID + "'";